# permissions question

Tags: permissions

I'm new to Ubuntu and setting permissions. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04

A folder has ownership by `www-data` user.

```
drwxrwxr-x 60 www-data www-data    12288 Nov 17 10:37 forms
```

I created a new user and put them in only the quality group.

I created a winscp ftp connection for their user name, and they can add files in that forms folder, as well as many others.

How do I go about figuring out why they have permission to view and add files?

Edit: Note the following also:

```
$ find /var/www/forms -group quality
/var/www/forms/Quality_managed
```

So `Quality_managed` should be the only folder in forms that she should be able to write to, correct?

Answer (score 1):

From the permissions on `/var/www/forms/`, `drwxrwxr-x`, group and owner can read, write, and execute; and anyone can read and execute.  So from what you have described, the new user should be able to read and execute, but not write to `/var/www/forms/`.

However, depending on file ownership, and settings on individual files, the users may still be able to modify files within `/var/www/forms/`.